# Exact Solution of Second Order Non-Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem with solution of differential equation on non-topological soliton $$\frac{d^2\phi(x)}{dx^2}+(w^2-\mu^2)\phi(x)+\phi(x)^2-a\phi(x)^3=0$$
I get some information that the ansatz for solving this differential equation $$\phi(x)^n=\frac{a}{b+c\cosh{Dx}}$$ but I don't know how to use this ansatz specially finding the constants $a,b,c,d,n$ or what is method using this ansatz?
Thank you

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Well, my guess would be to derive $\phi(x)$ with respect to x twice and substitute the ansatz into the equation along with it's 2nd derivative. The boundary conditions would be dependent on the problem (or unless stated otherwise, $\phi(0)=\ldots, \phi'(0)=\ldots$ )

Comment: @EmilioPisanty probably, but you'll get a different answer from a mathematician, explained through theorems and their proofs. I think asking a physicist for a physics related question would yield a more intuitive answer, or at least the explanation would be simpler.

Comment: @DominikCar There's no physics in the question as posed. If Kasyfil explicitly wants a physicist's perspective on the topic, it starts with actually asking for it (which is, by itself, not enough, either).

Comment: Isn't the constant $a$ already in the equation?

Answer (score 0):

This equation begs us to consider the inverse function $x(\phi)$ instead.

Rewriting the equation as:

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}+f(\phi)=0$$

And using the inverse function relation:

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=-\left(\frac{d \phi}{dx} \right)^3 \frac{d^2x}{d \phi^2}=-\frac{x''}{x'^3}$$

We obtain:

$$x''-f(\phi) x'^3=0$$

Introducing a new function:

$$u(\phi)=x'$$

We can write:

$$u'-f(\phi) u^3=0$$

Inegrating:

$$-\frac{1}{2 u^2}=\int f(\phi) d\phi+C_1= \\ =\int \left((w^2-\mu^2)\phi+\phi^2-a\phi^3 \right) d\phi+C_1=\frac{w^2-\mu^2}{2} \phi^2+\frac{\phi^3}{3}-\frac{a}{4}\phi^4 +C_1$$

Or:

$$u^2=-\frac{1}{C_1+(w^2-\mu^2) \phi^2+\frac{2}{3} \phi^3 - \frac{a}{2} \phi^4}$$

> $$u= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1-(w^2-\mu^2) \phi^2-\frac{2}{3} \phi^3 + \frac{a}{2} \phi^4}}$$

Integrating a second time, we obtain:

> $$x(\phi)= \pm \int \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{C_1-(w^2-\mu^2) \phi^2-\frac{2}{3} \phi^3 + \frac{a}{2} \phi^4}}+C_2$$

I believe we can find the exact form of this antiderivative in terms of elementary or simple special functions (like elliptic integrals), but I will leave it for later. In any case the above represents the exact implicit solution of the original ODE.

---

Not sure about the ansatz, I may check it out later, but this is how I would approach such an equation if I wasn't given any additional information.